# Are all CSS pseudo classes allowed in mPDF?

Tags: mpdf

Unfortunetly I am in a position where I cannot simply test this myself. I've looked through the documentation here:

https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html

and it lists nothing about Pseudo classes. I know from Googling that

`tr:nth-child(even)`

is allowed, but it doesnt mention any thing else.

Can I assume all Pseudo classes are ok?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `:nth-child` is the *only* "overall" pseudo-class selector you can use with mPDF. There is no support for others in the current version.

You can also use `:left` and `:right` along with `@page` pseudo-class selector.

All that is listed on the [manual page](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html) you linked.